# How to interlink daterange picker (AngularJS custom directive) to AngularUI-Select2 behaviour?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, daterangepicker

I'm using

1. [Angular UI - Select2 directive](http://angular-ui.github.com#directives-select2) to show an option box.
2. [Bootstrap Date-Range Picker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) to show a date picker

Both of them are working fine individually.

**Working of the Date picker**

Whenever the date range is changed, new data is fetched through AngularJS.
This is the code:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="MyController">

    <div id="reportrange" class="reportrange"
        my-date-picker="changeDate($startDate, $endDate)">
        <span></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Angular script

```
//directive code
    var mod = angular.module('my-app', ['ngResource', 'ui']);

    mod.directive('myDatePicker', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                $(element).daterangepicker({
                    //options now shown for brevity
                }, function (startDate, endDate) {
                    $('#reportrange span').html(startDate.toString('MMMM d, yyyy') + ' - ' + endDate.toString('MMMM d, yyyy'));

                    var fStartDate =  moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    var fEndDate = moment(endDate).add('days', 1).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

                    scope.$eval(attr.myDatePicker, {$startDate: fStartDate, $endDate: fEndDate});

                });

                var inEndDate = Date.today();
                var inStartDate = Date.today().add({ days: -29 });
                //Set the initial state of the picker label
                $('#reportrange span').html(inStartDate.toString('MMMM d, yyyy') + ' - ' + inEndDate.toString('MMMM d, yyyy'));
            }
        };
    });

//Controller code
function MyController($scope, $resource, $timeout) {
    var inEndDate = moment(Date.today()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var inStartDate =  moment(Date.today().add({ days: -29 })).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var User = $resource('/fetch?from=:from&to=:to', {from: inStartDate, to: inEndDate}, {
        getAll: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });

    $scope.changeDate = function(fromDate, toDate) {
        $scope.customers = User.getAll({from: fromDate, to: toDate});
    };

    $scope.customers = User.getAll();
}
```

This is working fine. I'm getting `customers` list for the selected range (fetched through $resource everytime the range is changed)

**Working of the Select2 AngularUI**

```
<select ui-select2 ng-model="selectedCity" >        
    <option value="1">City1</option>
    <option value="2">City2</option>    
    <option value="3">City3</option>        
</select>
```

This is also working fine.

The requirement is that whenever an option is selected (e.g. 2nd option, City2) I want to get `customers` list for the selected range for City2.
And while City2 is selected, user can change the date range too and get a new list of `customers` value.

So I'm stuck as to how to interlink Datetime picker and this select options? Kindly guide me.

I'm stuck. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add inside controller.

```
$scope.$watch('selectedCity', function(newVal, oldVal){
  if(newVal){ 
   $scope.customers = User.getAll({from: fromDate, to: toDate, city: newVal});
 }
});
```

this function will be executed when the selectedCity changes and you can get customers. You also need to store the selected start and end dates in the $scope object (within `$scope.changeDate`).

Comment: So you mean to say I should make a $resource again call from $watch? Can I somehow add the selectedCity (which is a scope var) the the directive, so that when the scope changes, the directive calls the $resource again?

Comment: $scope.$watch should be in the controller where the resource is already defined. The directive is for date pickers and should not have any mention of the city or any other business logic. That way you have a reusable date picker that can be used anywhere else.

Comment: Awesome, this sounds good...let me try in my code and get back to you. Thanks a lot, @Ketan.

Comment: Should I use ng-change on the select instead of watch? Which one is preferred?

Comment: I am not really sure. I have always used watch.